# WPF drag item from listbox and drop in textbox

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag an item from a listbox to a textbox in WPF.
I can't get any code that will let me do this.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281857/wpf-drag-and-drop-to-a-textbox?rq=1

Comment: I'd suggest checking out Bea Stollnitz's blog post about [dragging/dropping data bound items](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.UWwdv7VJNP0)

Answer (score 0):

Use selection change event of listbox

```
private void listBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem i = (ListBoxItem)listBox2.Items[listBox2.SelectedIndex];
    s = i.Content.ToString();
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox2, i.Content.ToString(), DragDropEffects.All);
}
```